# How to make a new array of strings derived from an old array, using a delimeter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have an array of strings and I want to make a new one joining the strings of the arrays until the delimeter character is shown.For example I have this array of strings:

```
["5", "2", "0", "1", "6", "2", "7", "0", "1", "9", "9", "0", "0", "", "5", "2", "0", "3", "4", "1", "1", "0", "2", "1", "9", "8", "4", ""]
```

and I want to make a new one like this:

```
["5201627019900","5203411021984"]
```

The delimeter of those items in the array is the `""` between them.Any help?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to use map and join to achieve this

Comment: Will the delimiter always be every 13th element in the array?

Comment: No it is just a character or an empty character like "" in my case

Comment: if the array is large then reduce() will work faster as compared to .map().join() 
https://jsperf.com/test-map-join-vs-reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = array.join("").trim().split(/\s/ /*or " " */);
```

Comment: It may be worth using `trim()` after `join()` as there's a trailing empty space too, so this would result in a 3 element array with the last element being empty

Comment: Now get rid of the commas and we're there :) `var result = array.join("").trim().replace(/,/g,"").split(" ");`

Comment: `array.join()` results in `"5,2,0,1,6,2,7,0,1,9,9,0,0, ,5,2,0,3,4,1,1,0,2,1,9,8,4, "`, or at least it does for me when I try it

Comment: Ah yes sorry, missed the quotes. You're absolutely right :)

Comment: @Jonasw This code just joins them all together ["52016270199005203411021984"]. I want this result: ["5201627019900","5203411021984"]

Comment: @iakwvina no it doenst

Comment: I don't see the same result at chrome's console...I don't understand what's wrong :/

Comment: @iakwvina may made a typo somewhere?

Comment: An empty character was in my array not " ", so I replaced it with a ";" and then splitted it:

array.join("").trim().replace(/\s/g,';').split(";");

Thanks @Jonasw for your help!

Comment: @iakwvina youre welcome ;)  i think you could do .split(/\s/) instead... And feel free to hit the green checkmark...

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = array.reduce((a,b) => { return a+b; }).trim().split(" ");
```